# ¿Cómo condicionar una petición AJAX antes de enviar el POST?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angular, jquery-ui

Tengo esa función, me gustaría poder condicionarlo antes de enviar el POST que valide un dato que envía y después con relación al resultado ejecutar la petición.

```
.preventDefault();  
                var formData= new FormData($("#asi")[0]);  
                formData.append("case",'ins_asig');  
                $.ajax({  
                    url: 'inserts.php',  
                    type: 'POST',  
                    data: formData,  
                    cache: false,  
                    contentType: false,    
                    processData: false,  
                    beforeSend: function(){  
                        $('.btn').val("GUARDANDO INFORMACIÓN ....")  
                    },  
                    error: function(){  
                        swal("ERROR","Ocurrió un error al Guardar la Información","error");  
                    },  
                    success: function(data){  
                        if(data.length == 0)  
                        {    

                            swal({title: 'Éxito',text: 'Infomación almacenada correctamente',type: 'success'},function() 
 {window.location="cat_inventario.php";});  
                        }  
                        else  
                        {  
                            swal("ERROR","Ocurrió un error al Guardar la Información"+data,"error");  
                        }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar mejor esto: *me gustaría poder condicionarlo antes de enviar el post que valide el dato que envía con un if verificandolo en una consulta sql*? Es imposible antes de la petición Ajax lanzar una consulta SQL, pues precisamente eso debe hacerse en el servidor y sin Ajax no puedes hacerlo. Sería interesante saber qué es lo que quieres validar y preguntarte por qué no traes esa información ya al cargar la página.

Comment: Claro, quiero que realice una condición del id por ejemplo que se va a enviar en la función ajax, que si se encuentra el bd  no la ejecute y si no  esta que lo  realice

Comment: Bueno pero eso no tienes que hacerlo del lado del cliente (antes de la petición Ajax), sino en el servidor. Imagino que te refieres a una consulta así más o menos: `SELECT nombre FROM persona WHERE id=?`  Le mandas el valor de `id` vía Ajax y en el servidor se ejecuta la consulta y viene de vuelta diciéndote si encontró o no datos y qué datos encontró, según lo que necesites: el nombre, el apellido o lo que sea. ¿Es algo así lo que quieres?

Comment: Si  algo así,  pero  quiero  que de esa consulta valide si  se encuentra, si no lo  encuentra que ejecute la función que publique arriba. no se si me doy a entender

Comment: No sé a qué te refieres con: *la función que publiqué arriba*. El código que se ejecute en el servidor te dirá si ese dato existe o no. Entonces en la parte `success` de Ajax tendrás que manejar la respuesta del servidor para actuar en consecuencia. No sé si me entiendes lo que quiero decirte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para llevar a cabo lo que dices requieres dos peticiones, una para validar el dato y otra para enviar la información. Otro caso es que solo envíes la petición y el servidor se encargue de procesarla con base a que dicha información exista o no en la base de datos.

Si optas por el camino 1 (por [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)) requieres realizar prácticamente peticiones concatenadas, ejemplo:

```js
// Se envia los datos para validación y se devuelve
// la promesa de jQuery.
function validar(formData) {
  let random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 15);

  return $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + random,
    // data: formaData,
    beforeSend: function () {
      document.writeln('Validando...');
    }
  });
}

// Se envían los datos.
function enviar(formData) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1',
    // data: formaData,
    beforeSend: function () {
      document.writeln('Enviando...');
    }
  })
    .done(function () {
      alert('¡Enviado!');
    })
    .fail(function () {
      alert('Error');
    });
}

// Se captura el evento submit
$('form').on('submit', function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  let formData = new FormData();
  
  validar(formData)
    .done(enviar.bind(this, formData))
    .fail(function () {
      alert('Dato ya existe.');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Los métodos `.done()` y `.fail()` sustituyen la funcionalidad de `success()` y `error()` respectivamente.

***Nota:*** el sitio [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com) funciona para solicitar datos de prueba, al solicitar un valor no existente me devolverá un 404 a lo que jQuery lo interpretará como un error y ejecutará el `.fail()`.